# python read text file remove \n

Tags: python

I have a text file, `foo.txt` which looks like this,

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. 
It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
```

When I use python to read this,

```
with open("foo.txt", "r+") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        print(line)
```

then my output is like this,

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 

Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 

It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. 

It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
```

How can I get rid of extra `\n` ??

Thanks,

Comment: `print(line.strip())`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [replace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=replace#bytes.replace) to replace `"\n"` with `""` in the text.

```py
with open("foo.txt", "r+") as f:
   lines = f.readlines()
   for line in lines:
       line.replace("\n","")
       print(line)
```

or can use `end` to cancel automatic `\n` in print.

```py
with open("foo.txt", "r+") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        print(line,end="")
```

The second may be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This should do

> print(line.rstrip('\n'))